# VdmComplex Changes Not Working with PATCH

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Using the SAP B1 .edmx with 3.39.0 and trying to update `DeliveryNotes` with new `DocumentPackages`. However, the list of `DocumentPackage` that eventually gets passed by the execution of the update operation is empty.

Code:

```
var packagesUpdateDocument = new Document();

packagesUpdateDocument.setDocEntry(1);

var documentPackages = new ArrayList<DocumentPackage>();
var documentPackage = new DocumentPackage();

documentPackage.setNumber(10);

documentPackages.add(documentPackage);

packagesUpdateDocument.setDocumentPackages(documentPackages);


var updateDeliveryPackagesRequest = service.withServicePath("etc")
                    .updateDeliveryNotes(packagesUpdateDocument);

var updateDeliveryPackagesResponse = updateDeliveryPackagesRequest.tryExecute(serviceLayerDestination);
```

Looking at the logs of the service layer I can see this is the request which was eventually sent by the client:

```
PATCH /b1s/v2/DeliveryNotes(1)

{"DocEntry":1,"DocumentPackages":[{}],"@odata.type":"SAPB1.Document"}
```

From my understanding, PATCH requests will automatically disregard anything the generated client deems as 'unchanged.'

Printing the changed fields:

```
System.out.println(packagesUpdateDocument.getChangedFields());
```

Yields:

```
{
  DocEntry=175017, 
  DocumentPackages=
    [DocumentPackage
      ( 
        super=VdmObject(customFields={}, 
        changedOriginalFields={}), 
        odataType=SAPB1.DocumentPackage, 
        number=10, 
      )
    ]
  .....
}
```

I believe the Package is not recording the fields which have changed. Although I am not certain.

Is there a step I am missing or is this a feature gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of SAP Cloud SDK **3.42.0** we support updating complex properties with PATCH out-of-the-box. See the [release notes](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#new-functionality) for more details.

Comment: @Conner The feature is now available

Comment: Perfect! I follow the release of the SDK pretty closely so I started using it on Friday. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a feature gap currently. `PATCH` will only consider properties of the root entity and navigation properties while disregarding changes in complex properties.

Until that is supported updating with `PUT` instead via the `.replacingEntity()` option should work.

Comment: Unfortunately the PUT operation isn't totally workable in this scenario as Document has hundreds of fields that cannot be updated, causing errors if you issue a PUT request.

Comment: I was able to use the generic client to make the request, so I think we should be okay for now.

Comment: Yeah that would have been my next suggestion. I'll update here once the SDK supports it natively.